# why chrome extensions not exctute in background tab page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using a chrome extension(third party) to download specific info automatically. When I open the target page in the background tab, the extension does not execute even the page has been loaded. When the page is visible, it can show the button on the page, after all elements show.
Is there any js script or setting that is stopping the extension to run ?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a js script. Google chrome automatically puts processes in background tabs on a lower priority to save resources for the user. Some events require user interaction to begin. Without knowing what you're attempting and what extension you're using, it's not possible to solve the problem.

Comment: Does the same thing happen with Edge Chromium?